Getting errorMessage": "Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)", in Lambda Python
I'm trying to create a slack bot using the slack api and an aws lambda function. Right now I just want it to respond with "Hi" whenever a user says "Hello". I'm getting this error when I test the code in the Lambda code editor. I'm very new to Lambda and I have been stuck on this for a while. Any help is greatly appreciated!
The Full Error:
Response
{
  "errorMessage": "Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)",
  "errorType": "JSONDecodeError",
  "requestId": "f8f871e9-efdf-4313-acca-55763d22f1e6",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 32, in lambda_handler\n    incomingevent = json.loads(event[\"event\"][\"text\"])\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.11/json/__init__.py\", line 346, in loads\n    return _default_decoder.decode(s)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.11/json/decoder.py\", line 337, in decode\n    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.11/json/decoder.py\", line 355, in raw_decode\n    raise JSONDecodeError(\"Expecting value\", s, err.value) from None\n"
  ]
}

Function Logs
START RequestId: f8f871e9-efdf-4313-acca-55763d22f1e6 Version: $LATEST
LAMBDA_WARNING: Unhandled exception.
[ERROR] JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 32, in lambda_handler
    incomingevent = json.loads(event["event"]["text"])
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.11/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.11/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.11/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from NoneEND RequestId: f8f871e9-efdf-4313-acca-55763d22f1e6

import os
from six.moves import urllib
import json

def send_text_response(event, response_text):
    SLACK_URL = "https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage"
    channel_id = event["event"]["channel"]
    user = event["event"]["user"]
    bot_token = os.environ["BOT_TOKEN"]
    data = urllib.parse.urlencode({
        "token": bot_token,
        "channel": channel_id,
        "text": response_text,
        "user": user,
        "link_names": True
    })
    data = data.encode("ascii")
    request = urllib.request.Request(SLACK_URL, data=data, method="POST")
    request.add_header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    res = urllib.request.urlopen(request).read()
    print('res:', res)

def check_message(text):
    if 'Hello' in text:
        return 'Hi'
    return None


def is_bot(event):
    return 'bot_profile' in event['event']


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    incomingevent = json.loads(event["event"]["text"])
    print('event', incomingevent)
    if not is_bot(event):
        message = check_message(event["event"]["text"])
        if message:
            send_text_response(event, message)

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': 'OK'
    }


It might be that you should use event["text"] instead of event["event"]["text"]. I suggest you add print(event) to the very beginning of your lambda_handler() function so you can see what is actually in the event.
